# Native JSON parser issue

Tags: bug, json

It seems that json.serialize method converts null to String 'null'

```
System.debug(String.isEmpty(null));
Contact con = null;
String jsonCon = JSON.serialize(con);
System.debug(jsonCon);
System.debug(String.isEmpty(jsonCon));
```

Results in debug:

```
15:21:35.039 (39195000)|USER_DEBUG|[1]|DEBUG|true
15:21:35.039 (39503000)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|null
15:21:35.039 (39551000)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|false
```

Comment: OK, but what's your question? Are you looking for advice on how to handle this or just confirmation that this is expected behavior?

Comment: I except it working as described in that function String.isEmpty()
"....Returns true if the specified String is empty ('') or null; otherwise, returns false...."

Comment: I think the issue is that json.serialize returns 'null' rather than returning null. I think there is a difference in JSON between {ID:"null"} and {"ID":null}

Comment: @grigriforce it looks to me like it's properly returning null, and not the string 'null'. https://gist.github.com/4242074

Comment: @Mikey It does this correctly for everything but strings. https://gist.github.com/4246349

Comment: @grigriforce very interesting...

Answer (score 11):

As per the [json](http://www.json.org/) spec, null is represented by the keyword null, so this seems right.

Comment: but it seems like the json.serialize is returning 'null' rather than null for strings. https://gist.github.com/4246349

Comment: that is correct the value null should generate the keyword null. (think about the case where you have a map with a key foo and a value null, you'd get { "foo" : null }

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4248650